# How to write an X11 app that follows the cursor

Tags: linux, unix, x11

I'd like to write a Linux screen magnifier that's customized to my liking. Ideally, the magnified window would be a square about 150 pixels wide that follows the mouse cursor wherever it goes.

Is it possible to do this in X11? Would it be easier to have an application window that follows the mouse around, or would it be better (or possible) to forget about the window altogether and just make the mouse pointer a 150x150 square that magnifies whatever's underneath?

Comment: Which would you like? Pick one. (xmag or xeyes, both of which exist and are widely open source) Also, please accept an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the source to [xeyes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeyes)?

Answer (score 2):

This actually already exists, it's called [Xmag](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xmag.1.html) (do a Google search for additional info). You might want to check out the source code for it if you want to know how it works.

*EDIT*: looks like I misread your question a little bit... if you want a magnified square to follow the mouse pointer around, I suppose it should be possible, but I don't know the technical details of how you'd do it. Regardless, the place to start is probably by looking at Xmag as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this can run as its own app or would have to be integrated into your window manager.  Either way, you would need libx11 (might have a different name from distro to distro).  Also, I would suggest taking a look at [swarp](http://www.suckless.org/programs/swarp.html).  I know this is not even close to what you are talking about, but the source code is only 35 lines and it shows what can be done with libx11.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally make that a frameless window that always stays atop with a 1px hole in the middle. The events that the user makes (Mouse clicks, keypresses, whatever) is passed to the window below.

And when the user moves it's cursor it is ought to be visible to your window and you just move it over a bit. For the magnifying part, well - that is left as an exercise to the reader (Because I do not know how to do that as of yet ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Texworks comes with such a feature to inspect the pdf resulting from typesetting a latex source. You can also choose between a square or a circular magnifier. See https://www.tug.org/texworks/ for access to the code which can serve a launchpad.